# How data is being retrieved from the blockchain using only the address of a smart contract

Tags: blockchain, contract-invocation, addresses, data

Sorry if I didn't fully clarify the question; it was quite challenging for me to do so.
This is a smart contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract GameItem {
    uint256 number = 10;

    function store(uint256 _number) public {
        number = _number;
    }

    function retrieve() public view returns (uint256 magic_number) {
        return number;
    }
}
```

And when we deploy this to blockchain we get a contract address `address_1`.

1. If we call the retrieve then we simply read the data from the block with address `address_1`. (Totally understandable)
2. we call the store function and store `20`, This will create a new block that is been added to blockchain somewhere after the previous block.
3. if we try to call the retrieve again then how we are able to get the latest value `20` comes as result even after we don't have the address of new block (we only have the `address_1`).

[image]
You can see here every time we try to store, we have the same from and to addresses.

> `From` is my wallet address
> `to` is the contract address

I tried, but I couldn't figure out how the data was correctly fetched even though we don't have the block address.

It would be fantastic if someone could clarify my issue and explain how it functions.
***Thanks***

Answer (score 0):

@praval, first you need to understand that block don't have any address. accounts and smart contracts have address a unique identifier. and we've transaction hash to read transaction details unique identifier of tansaction.
To read detail transaction hash and address wise, visit this https://goerli.etherscan.io/txs

Comment: So the data is read as follows: First, we obtain the transaction hashes using the contract address, after which we select the most recent one from which we can obtain the block hash, block number, and other details. I guess, these all details are sufficient to read a particular transaction from the blockchain.